# Validate phone number with starting from certain number only in inputmask jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I am trying to validate phone number as following. After 61 it should be starting from 2 or 3 or 6 only. Examples are as follows.
61-245623463 : valid
61-345623456 : valid
61-445623423 : not valid
61-645623485 : valid

My current code is as follows. But it doesen't work.

```
$("#mask_aus_phone").inputmask({mask: "61-2 9999 9999"});
$("#mask_aus_phone").inputmask({mask: "61-3 9999 9999"});
$("#mask_aus_phone").inputmask({mask: "61-6 9999 9999"});
```

I tried as follows also. But it also doesn't work.

```
$("#mask_aus_phone").inputmask({mask: "61-{2,3,6} 9999 9999"});
```

Can someone help me to validate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can feed a regex into the input mask:

```
$('#mask_aus_phone').inputmask('Regex', { 
    regex: "^61-[236]"
});
```

I used the regex `^61-[236]`, but you could also use a positive lookahead and assert that the number following `61-` is either 2, 3, or 6:

```
^61-(?:(?=[236]).)+
```

**Update:**

You didn't make it explicit, but if you want to limit the total number of digits after `61-` to 9, then you can try:

```
^61-[236]\d{8}$
```

**Demo:**

## Regex101

Comment: Hi Tim, It is working fine. Can you guide me how to limit numbers after entering 2 or 3 or 6. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Last regex seems not working on my site. After entering 61-2 , It is not allowing to enter any number. What can be the problem. My code is $('#mask_aus_phone').inputmask('Regex', {
        regex: "^61-[236]\d{8}$"
    });

Comment: Try this one: `^61-[236][0-9]{8}$`... every regex engine has its own flavor and way of doing things.  Anyway, the regex I gave should work across most engines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, you can build a small dictionary through the recent [phone extension](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/4.x/README_phone.md):

```js
Inputmask.extendAliases({
  my_phone: {
    alias: "abstractphone",
    placeholder: '#',
    showMaskOnFocus: false,
    phoneCodes: [{
      mask: "61-2 #### ####",
      region_name: 'Dois',
      desc_en: "Second region"
    }, {
      mask: "61-3 #### ####",
      region_name: 'Três',
      desc_en: "Third region"
    }, {
      mask: "61-6 #### ####",
      region_name: 'Seis',
      desc_en: "6th region"
    }],
    onKeyValidation: function() {
      let mt = $(this).inputmask("getmetadata");
      $('#jqma span').text(
       mt['region_name']+' - '+mt['desc_en']).css(
       'color', `#${Math.floor(Math.random() *
       0x1000000).toString(16).padStart(6, 0)}`
      );
      console.log(mt);
    }
  }
});
$('#jqma input').inputmask("my_phone");
```

```css
span {color:#37e;font-weight:bold;transition: color 1s}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/4.x/dist/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/4.x/dist/inputmask/inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/4.x/dist/inputmask/inputmask.phone.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/4.x/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/4.x/dist/inputmask/phone-codes/phone.js"></script>

<p id="jqma"><label>Extended phone alias: <input placeholder="61-# #### ####"/></label> <span/>
</p>
```

This dynamic validator example was [based in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49833062/1326147). The explanation is as follows:

- the phone extension is like an [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), which is referenced through the `alias: "abstractphone"`;
- [`phone.js`](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/4.x/dist/inputmask/phone-codes/phone.js) "implements" the alias `phone`, which has predefined rules such as numeric/integer only masks (if most of the world's phone numbers were valid for that input, this would be enough to validate them all: `$('#mask_aus_phone').inputmask('phone')`);
- by extending an alias with the alias property `abstractphone`, one can define several items containing specific masks with related *metadata* that can be dynamically fetched when validating.

Comment: In this, when we press other than 2,3,6, by default it takes 2. can we restrict this?